# SQL: pull distinct values form 1 column with all values from 2nd column

Tags: sql

Its easier to explain what I need to do with an example;

table looks like this

```
Col 1,       Col 2  
1,            a  
1,            b  
2,            a  
2,            b  
2,            c
```

I need a query to return something like

```
1,a,b  
2,a,b,c
```

Comment: Nothing, I don't really know where to start and had no luck search google to find a place to start

Comment: In your case, the solution could be very different depending upon which database you have: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: How would be do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

You would want a line such as:

```
UPDATE t
SET    t.dupcustodians = dt.custadmin
FROM   tbldoc t
       INNER JOIN (SELECT t1._dupid,
                          (SELECT DISTINCT custadmin + ', '
                           FROM   tbldoc t2
                           WHERE  t2._dupid = t1._dupid
                           ORDER  BY custadmin + ', '
                           FOR XML PATH('')) AS custadmin
                   FROM   tbldoc t1
                   GROUP  BY _dupid) AS dt
         ON t._dupid = dt._dupid
            ;
```

I had a similar problem where everything had a name in the "CustAdmin" field and then they all had potentially duplicate _DupID values.  I wanted it to list out in a new field "DupCustodians" all the names that were there when the _DupID values were alike from one record to the next.  So swap those names with the field names you need (and don't forget to change the table names, of course) and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are using MySQL, then you can do this:

```
SELECT Col1, GROUP_CONCAT(Col2)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Col1
```

Other databases that don't have the MySQL specific GROUP_CONCAT function might require a more complex query.

Comment: How to do this in PostgreSQL?